# Install Virtualbox on Linux Mint 17.3 with upgraded kernel 4.4

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, linux-mint, kernel

Fresh Linux Mint 17.3 install on a Thinkpad T460. Upgraded kernel from 3.19 to 4.4.0-15 to get WiFi working.

Now can't get Virtualbox to run. I need Virtualbox to run Vagrant.

```
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.4.0-15-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.4/build/make.log for more information.
 * Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules [ OK ] 
 * Starting VirtualBox kernel modules
 * No suitable module for running kernel found
```

/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.4/build/make.log:

```
DKMS make.log for virtualbox-5.0.4 for kernel 4.4.0-15-generic (x86_64)
Tue Apr  5 22:56:08 SAST 2016
make: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-15-generic'
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.4/build/built-in.o
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.4/build/vboxdrv/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.4/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.4/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c: In function ‘VBoxDrvLinuxUnload’:
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.4/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:488:8: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
     rc = misc_deregister(&gMiscDeviceUsr);
        ^
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.4/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:493:8: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
     rc = misc_deregister(&gMiscDeviceSys);
        ^
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.4/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.4/build/vboxdrv] Error 2
make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.0.4/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-15-generic'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VirtualBox 5.0.5 and older cannot compile on Linux kernel 4.3 and newer.  This was fixed in VirtualBox 5.0.6, released on 02 October 2015.

From [the changelog](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog) for VirtualBox 5.0.6:

> This is a maintenance release. The following items were fixed and/or added:
>
> - Linux hosts: Linux 4.3 compile fixes

The fix is to upgrade VirtualBox to version 5.0.6 or newer.  If you use the VirtualBox Debian repository and want to remain on the VirtualBox 5.0.x line, run this command:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade virtualbox-5.0
```

Otherwise, download and install the latest version of VirtualBox from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).

---

#### Additional Resources

- [Discussion about the fix](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=70150)
- [VirtualBox changeset that fixed the issue](https://www.virtualbox.org/changeset/57839/vbox)